# XNA vs Unity for RTS Games

Tags: xna, unity-game-engine

I realize that Unity is a game engine and XNA is just a framework, but it seems like either platform could potentially work for this purpose.

Which platform has more support in the regard of built-in or community built code/open source projects related to RTS games?

I know that there is going to be a lot of scripting/programming involved either way but if I didn't have to worry about making my own fast and efficient collision detection, pathfinding algorithms, client/server networking (the more nitty gritty stuff), it would greatly speed up development and allow me to concentrate more on the gameplay and design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really **don't** want to be messing with the nitty-gritty as you just said, use an engine.

Even though a lot of stuff is high-level in XNA compared to many other frameworks, you still are ultimately responsible for the code your game is running - down to the smallest nitty-gritty detail.

This really goes for any genre by the way.

However, people can **write** engines using XNA that attempt to take care of the nitty-gritty for you, just as something like Unity would.

In the way of Unity, since it's already an engine you can't really write one in it - but people still write helpful scripts that you can make use of. Doing a bit of poking around on UnityAnswers, [there are plenty written with RTS's in mind](http://answers.unity3d.com/search.html?redirect=search/search&q=rts): It'd be your job to integrate the ones you need within your Unity game.

So honestly it comes down to which option provides more/better resources for your purposes; hope I've gotten you started at least.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like I have my work cut out for me either direction I take. Im probably going to take the Unity route since writing an entire engine doesn't seem that appealing. Hopefully there isn't any serious limitations that I'll run into.

Answer (score 0):

Unity is pretty much geared toward games that require a lot of "simulation" elements (physics, collision detection, independent entities).  If you don't want to worry about all that stuff, Unity would be your best bet.